# Equivalent function of R's "%in%" for Stata

Tags: function, r, stata

Is there an equivalent function of "%in%" from R for Stata?

Comment: please describe what this operator does - people who can answer will probably know Stata, but may not know R

Comment: It returns a boolean: true is lfs is in the rhs list, false otherwise.

Comment: it's best if you add essential details to the question, rather than hope they are found in the comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned, it's hard to tell what you need from the question.  `inlist()` might work, or it might not depending on the setting.

I find that Stata's `macro lists` functions are invaluable. Store your list in a macro (local or global) and then a [suite of useful commands](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?macrolists) are available:

```
local list   a b c d d e 
local search c 
local search_in_list : list search in list
di    `search_in_list'
```

These can be calculated on the fly:

```
if `: list search in list' {
    actions if true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Stata does not offer the same flexible tool, but `inlist` will cover the basic operation that you might be looking for, as in `count if inlist(country,"FR","US","DE")`.

Answer (score 1):

working with lists proper is one way, you could also just treat the rhs like a string and treat the lhs as a regex, use regexm()