# What is the equivalent of Stata function inlist() in R?

Tags: r, command, stata

Stata's [inlist](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0026) allows us to refer to the real or string values of a variable. I was wondering whether `R` has such a function.

**Examples:**

I want to choose eight states from the variable `state` (you can think this as column `state` in any dataframe  where `state` takes 50 string values (states of United States)).

```
    inlist(state,"NC","AZ","TX","NY","MA","CA","NJ")
```

I want to choose nine values of age from the variable `age` (you can think this as column `age` in any dataframe  where `age` takes numerical values from 0 to 90).

```
    inlist(age,16, 24, 45, 54, 67,74, 78, 79, 85)
```

Question:

```
age<-c(0:10) # for this problem age takes values from 0 to 10 only
data<-as.data.frame(age) # age is a variable of data frame data
data$m<-ifelse(c(1,7,9)%in%data$age,0,1) # generate a variable m which takes  value 0 if age is 1, 7, and 8 and 1, otherwise
Expected output: 
   age m
1    0 1
2    1 0
3    2 1
4    3 1
5    4 1
6    5 1
7    6 1
8    7 0
9    8 1
10   9 0
11  10 1
```

Comment: I believe you might be looking for `match()` or `%in%` but am not too familiar with the `inlist` function from Stata.

Comment: it would help if you defined `state` and `age` and showed the expected output ...

Comment: @Ananda and @ Ben: Sorry for not being more explicit. I have now edited the question and I hope that it is more clear.

Comment: http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?inlist() is a more concise and direct source of information. In Stata `inlist()` is a function, and _not_ a command.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5091426/1317221

Comment: question is still not quite clear enough.  Could you please give an *explicit* example along with the expected output?

Comment: @BenBolker I have edited the question along with the expected output.

Comment: Edited to refer to `inlist()` as a Stata function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want `%in%`:

```
statevec <- c("NC","AZ","TX","NY","MA","CA","NJ")
state <- c("AZ","VT")
state %in% statevec ## TRUE FALSE
agevec <- c(16, 24, 45, 54, 67,74, 78, 79, 85) 
age <- c(34,45)
age %in% agevec ## FALSE TRUE
```

**edit**: working on updated question.

Copying from @NickCox's link:

```
inlist(z,a,b,...)
      Domain:       all reals or all strings
      Range:        0 or 1
      Description:  returns 1 if z is a member of the remaining arguments;
                        otherwise, returns 0.  All arguments must be reals
                        or all must be strings.  The number of arguments is
                        between 2 and 255 for reals and between 2 and 10 for
                        strings.
```

However, I'm not quite sure how this matches up with the original question.  I don't know Stata well enough to know if `z` can be a vector or not: it doesn't sound that way, in which case the original question (considering `z=state` as a vector) doesn't make sense. If we consider that it *can* be a vector then the answer would be `as.numeric(state %in% statevec)` -- I think.

Edit: ***Update by Ananda***

Using your updated data, here's one approach, again using `%in%`:

```
data <- data.frame(age=0:10)
within(data, {
    m <- as.numeric(!age %in% c(1, 7, 9))
})
   age m
1    0 1
2    1 0
3    2 1
4    3 1
5    4 1
6    5 1
7    6 1
8    7 0
9    8 1
10   9 0
11  10 1
```

This matches your expected output, by using `!` (NOT) to invert the sense of `%in%`.  It seems to be a little backwards from the way I would think about it (normally, 0=`FALSE`="is not in the list" and 1=`TRUE`="is in the list") and my reading of Stata's definition, but if it's what you want ...

Or one can use `ifelse` for more potential flexibility (i.e. values other than 0/1): substitute `within(data, { m <- ifelse(age %in% c(1, 7, 9),0,1)})` in the code above.

Comment: @Ananda: I have updated the question. Can you please check that?

Comment: @BenBolker, Sorry about the messy edits! Couldn't keep track of all the edits to the question! ;)

Comment: @Ben, this is a scalar function, and for a good reason, probably: I am not sure how to interpret the many-to-many matches. Should `inlist( c(1,7,9),1)` evaluate to TRUE? Should `inlist( c(1,7,9), c(9,7,1) )` evaluate to TRUE? Should only `inlist( c(1,7,9), c(1,7,9), c(2,3,5) )` evaluate to true? When `inlist()` is encountered in the variable context (recall that Stata only works with one rectangular object called data), it is evaluated for every observation in the data set.

Comment: well, R uses sensible definitions for its `%in%` operator (if maybe not the ones you want, and maybe not exactly equivalent to `inline`): `c(1,7,9) %in% 1` gives `TRUE FALSE FALSE`; `c(1,7,9) %in% c(9,7,1)` gives `TRUE TRUE TRUE` (all three elements in the first operand match elements of the second operand). I don't know about the version with >2 arguments (`%in%` only allows two); I would probably make the R definition as `a %in% union(b,c,d,...)`

Comment: @AnandaMahto: As far as I understand, as.numeric generates 0 or 1. But, ifelse allows other values too, e.g., 10 or 50. I would like to stick with ifelse:
`within(data, {
 m <- ifelse(age %in% c(1, 7, 9),0,1)
 })`
Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @BenBolker I think it would be more R like to return a logical vector - I suspect stata doesn't have the equivalent and so has to use 0 and 1.