# R: How to loop over variable names using number indexes (like in Stata)

Tags: r, loops, stata

I've been trying unsuccessfully to replicate in R the following Stata loop:

```
forvalues i=1/10 {
    replace var`i'= a if other_var`i'==b
}
```

So far I've got this as the closest attempt:

```
for(i in 1:10) {
df <- df %>%
                      mutate(get(paste("var",i,sep="")) = 
                      ifelse(get(paste("other_var",i,sep=""))==b
                      ,a
                      ,get(paste("var",i,sep=""))))
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"survey_data <- survey_data %>%
                      mutate(paste("offer",i,"_accepted",sep="") ="
```

If I change the variable to be mutated to a simple variable name, it works, so I'm guessing my code is OK for the "right-hand side of the mutation", but for some reason it's not OK for the "left-hand side".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```
df <- structure(list(var1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
                     var2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
                     var3 = c(1,2, 3, 4), 
                     var4 = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
                     other_var1 = c(1, 0, 1, 0), 
                     other_var2 = c(0,1, 0, 1), 
                     other_var3 = c(1, 1, 0, 0), 
                     other_var4 = c(0, 0, 1,1)), 
                class = "data.frame", 
                row.names = c(NA, -4L))
# var1 var2 var3 var4 other_var1 other_var2 other_var3 other_var4
# 1    1    1    1    1          1          0          1          0
# 2    2    2    2    2          0          1          1          0
# 3    3    3    3    3          1          0          0          1
# 4    4    4    4    4          0          1          0          1
## Values to replace based on OP original question
a <- 777
b <- 1
## Iter along all four variables avaible in df
for (i in 1:4) {
  df <-   within(df, {
    assign(paste0("var",i),  ifelse(get(paste0("other_var",i)) %in% c(b), ## Condition  
                                    a,                                    ## Value if Positive
                                    get(paste0("var",i)) ))               ## Value if Negative
  })
}
```

which results in the following output:

```
# var1 var2 var3 var4 other_var1 other_var2 other_var3 other_var4
# 1  777    1  777    1          1          0          1          0
# 2    2  777  777    2          0          1          1          0
# 3  777    3    3  777          1          0          0          1
# 4    4  777    4  777          0          1          0          1
```

The solution doesn't look like a *one-line-solution*, but it actually *is* one, a quite dense one tho; hence let's see how it works by its foundation components.

`within()`: I don't want to repeat what other people have excellently explained, so for the `within()` usage, I gently refer you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295236/what-is-the-equivalent-of-stata-function-inlist-in-r).

### The: `assign(paste0("var",i), X)` part.

Here I am following that [@han-tyumi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65815505/10714156) did in his answer, meaning recover the name of the variables using `paste0()` and assign them the value of `X`(to be explained) using the `assign()` function.

### Let's talk about `X`.

Before I referenced `assign(paste0("var",i), X)`. Where, indeed, `X` is equal to  `ifelse(get(paste0("other_var",i)) %in% c(b), a, get(paste0("var",i)) )`.

### Inside the `ifelse()`:

#### The condition:

First, I recover the values of variable `other_var(i)` (with i = 1,2,3,4) combining the function `get()` with `paste0()` while looping. Then, I use the `%in%` operator to check whether the value assigned to variable `b`(on my example, the number 1) was contained on variable `other_var(i)` or not; this generates a TRUE or FALSE depending if the condition is met.

#### The `TRUE` part of the `ifelse()` function.

This is the simplest part if the condition is met then assign, `a` (which in my example is equal to `777`).

#### The `FALSE` part of the `ifelse()` function.

`get(paste0("var",i))`: which is the value of the variable itself (meaning, if the condition is not meet, then keep the variable unaltered).

Answer (score 2):

This solution is very inelegant, but I think does exactly what you want.

```
var1 <- "x"
var2 <- "y"
var3 <- "z"

other_var1 <- 1
other_var2 <- 0
other_var3 <- 1

df <- data.frame(var1, other_var1, var2, other_var2, var3, other_var3)

for(i in 1:3){
  var_name <- paste("df$var", i, sep = "")
  other_var_name <- paste("df$other_var", i, sep = "")
  if (eval(parse(text = other_var_name)) == 1){
    assign(var_name, "a")
  }
}
```

There are three key ingredients here. First the `paste()` function to create the names of the variables in the current iteration of the loop. Second, the `eval(parse(foo))` combo to reference the actual variable whose name is stored as string in `foo`. Third, using `assign()` to assign values to a variable (as opposed to using `<-`).

Comment: I like a lot the readability of this answer @han-tyumi. It is crystal clear what you are doing; however, probably less typing could have been done using `with()` getting rid of the `df$var`; regardless, I endorse it :) +1!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like FAQ 7.21.

The most important part of that answer is at the end where is says to use a list instead.

Trying to work on a group of global variables in R leads to complicated code that is hard to read and even harder to debug.

If you instead put those variables into a single list, then you can access them by name or position and use tools like `lapply` or the `purrr` package (part of tidyverse) to process everything in the list (or some of the things in the list using `map_at` or `map_if` from `purrr`).

If tell us more about what you are trying to accomplish, we may be able to give a much simpler example of how to do it.